# Wordpress additional fields

Tags: wordpress

In my WP installation I have a category called "books".  In addition to the title and body text I'd like to add a field called "ISBN" that must be filled in for every post in this category. In the Blog category this field should not be displayed in the admin.

In Expression Engine and Drupal it's quite straightforward to add fields like this but I'm not sure about how this works in WP. What's the best way of doing this in WP 3.2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress this can be done by adding meta-data to posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: How do you manage those on a per-category basis? It seems I can add fields for every post, but I have to add those fields manually every time I create a post in said category?

Comment: By default you'll have to add them everytime, but I can't imagine there isn't a plugin that allows you to specifiy them for a category